# Why is water escaping my downspouts onto the concrete pad?

Tags: drainage, gutters

A post on what I should do with a new house suggested that I walk the lawn when it was raining cats and dogs. I took that advice this weekend and noticed something very interesting about my downspouts. I'm seeing what appears to be water flowing out of the downspouts into my concrete pad on 2 of my downspouts. Any thoughts if this is normal (doesn't appear to be) or it is something as simple let it try and then simply apply silicone around the rim to prevent the water from flowing out:

Downspot 1 video:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/gSCryRpPzfSpbcSQA

Downspot 2 video:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/QsYs7V1UvSqGKyB28

Added photos per request below.
[image: Down 1]

[image: Down 2]

Answer (score 2):

You have buried downspouts that discharge somewhere else. This could be out in your yard, or the sewer system. Most municipalities are trying to get rid of downspouts connected directly to the sewer system, but that's not the point of your question.

You need to figure out why the water is overflowing and fix that, rather than sealing up the connection. Gravity is helping the water flow down,  and that should be plenty of force to keep the water moving past the connection if there is no obstruction. The fact that it's overflowing means that pipe is blocked somewhere. Pull apart that connection and see if you can find a clog. It could be a ways down the line which can be a challenge to unplug. You may need an inspection camera and/or drain snake.

For this reason you shouldn't connect your gutters directly to a downspout in this fashion. There should be a clean-out for debris and leaves to collect to prevent this. This would go in-line between the gutter downspout and the tube that's buried in the concrete. Search "downspout filter" to find these products.

Comment: This piqued my curiosity about having PVC discharge drainage water at a few feet above the house's grade elevation by using the downspout's water column to push water through instead of running everything downhill. Kind of an extreme popup emitter. Is it possible that there's a popup emitter on this line and that it's above the downspout connection?

Comment: are downspouts generally push fit?  or do I need special tools to take the bottom part out?  I was thinking taking tin snips, cutting it and seeing what the initial damage is (and then installing a filter as mentioned and then just press fitting  it all back together.

Comment: Push fit with a sheet-metal screw or two to keep them from popping loose, in most cases.

Comment: Yeah, to address the proposed solution in your question, downspouts are never sealed with caulk. Sealed downspouts are _plumbing_, and that's a different animal, done with actual pipe and pipe cement.